# Crontab Python Script Execution (Can't find settings config file)

Tags: python, linux, cron

My Crontab -l

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

00 8,20 * * * python /home/tomi/amaer/controller.py >>/tmp/out.txt 2>&1
```

My controller.py has config file settings.cfg also it uses other script in the folder it's located (I chmoded only controller.py)

The error

```
1;31mIOError^[[0m: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'settings.cfg'
```

I have no idea how to fix this? Please help me?

Edit: The part that read the config file

```
def main():
    config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open("settings.cfg"),"r")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I initially wrote in my comment, this is because you are using relative path to the current working directory. However, that is not going to be the same when running all this via the cron executable rather than the python interpreter directly via the shebang.

Your current code would look for the "settings.cfg" in the current working directory which is where the cron executable resides, and not your script. Hence, you would need to change your code logic to using absolute paths by the help of the "os" built-in standard module.

Try to following line:

```
import os
...
def main():
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser() 
    scriptDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    settingsFilePath = os.path.join(scriptDirectory, "settings.cfg")
    config.readfp(open(settingsFilePath,"r"))
```

This will get your the path of your script and then appends the "settings.cfg" with the appropriate dir separator for your operating system which is Linux in this particular case.

If the location of the config file changes any time in the future, you could use the argparse module for processing a command line argument to handle the config location properly, or even without it simply just using the first argument after the script name like `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: What do you mean by future? The snippet works for your use case now, too, doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is looking for `settings.cfg` in its current working directory.

This working directory will not be the same when cron executes the job, hence the error

You have two "easy" solutions:

- Use an absolute path to the config file in your script (`/home/tomi/amaer/config.cfg`)
- CD to the appropriate directory first in your crontab (`cd /home/tomi/amaer/ && python /home/tomi/amaer/controller.py`)

The "right" solution, though, would be to pass your script a parameter (or environment variable) that tells it where to look for the config file.

It's not exactly good practice to assume your config file will always be lying just next to your script.

---

You might want to have alook at this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job